# Declare an SQL variable in Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, scalar

I have connected Java to SSMS and can call data from the server no problems using something like this:

```
String cell = "SELECT [Close] FROM ExcelData WHERE id_num = 3";
Statement st4 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs4 = st4.executeQuery(cell);

while (rs4.next())
{
    Float close = rs4.getFloat("close");
    System.out.format("%s\n", close);
}
```

When I replace the `"SELECT [Close] FROM ExcelData WHERE id_num = 3"` to `"SELECT @SMA"` I get the much questioned "Must declare the scalar variable `@SMA`.

I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Why do you want to do `SELECT @SMA`? Do you know what it means?

Comment: Sure, I have created several variables in SSMS, @SMA being one of them, I want to call them from SSMS into Java. Not sure if this answers your question?

Comment: A variable is specific to the session, so you can't define a variable in SSMS and then retrieve it in Java.

Comment: *"I have created several variables in SSMS"* Then create the same variables, using the same syntax, from Java, e.g. `String cell = "DECLARE @SMA int; SET @SMA = 42; SELECT @SMA"`, and you'll get back a result set with one row and one column with value 42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question to help others who may need to know this...
It cannot be done. The work around is to create a table in SQL and insert the variable into the table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SMA
CREATE TABLE SMA  (
SMA_Price DECIMAL (6,5),
)
INSERT INTO SMA VALUES (@SMA);

SELECT * FROM SMA;
```

You can then call "SELECT * FROM SMA" from Java.